# Why do I have to press spacebar in order to have my condition recognised?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I am currently learning C# and I'm trying to make a rather simple text-based game in the vscode console. I want to add a feature that lets the user choose gender and a class. I did this using an if statement. However, when running the program, the code needs me to press the spacebar before the condition in order to recognize it. I think I have tried everything and still haven't found a solution.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int classa=0; 
        meniu(classa);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static int meniu(int clasa = 0, int gen = 0){
        text="Vrei sa fie";
        scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        text="masculin";
        scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        text="sau";
        scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
        text = "feminin";
        scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
        Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.White;
        text="?";
        scriere(text);
        //this is where the important program begins
        string raspuns;
        string gen1="masculin";
        string gen2="feminin";
        raspuns=Console.ReadLine();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        while(n!=0){

            switch(raspuns){
                
                case "masculin":  //here, i believe, is the problem. Instead of only typing "masculin", the user has to type " masculin"
                    gen=1;
                    text="Ai ales un personaj masculin.";
                    scriereFaraInput(text);
                    n=0;
                    break;
                
                case "feminin":
                    gen=2;
                    text="Ai ales un personaj feminin.";
                    scriereFaraInput(text);
                    n=0;
                    break;
                
                default:
                    text="Alegere invalida.";
                    scriereFaraInput(text); 
                    text="Vrei sa fie";
                    scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    text="masculin";
                    scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    text="sau";
                    scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
                    text = "feminin";
                    scriereFaraEnterInput(text);
                    Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.White;
                    text="?";
                    scriere(text);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    raspuns=Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
            }
        }
   }
```

I would like to know why is this happening and how could I remove it.

Comment: As an aside, you don't need to assign to a variable before calling a function. e.g. `text="Alegere invalida."; scriereFaraInput(text);` should just be `scriereFaraInput("Alegere invalida.");`

Comment: Nor do you need to call `ToCharArray` on a string to iterate over the characters. Just index the string directly.

Comment: What input are you providing (typing) for `raspuns=Console.ReadLine();`?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with the debugger and inspecting the switch variable? (or some logging statements)

Comment: Are you sure it's the space bar you have to hit and not the Enter key? `ReadLine()` requires you to enter a line of text, and therefore needs a new line character to end input.

Comment: I think the problem is that there is an earlier method call that blocks until the user hits a key. The subsequent `ReadLine()` and `switch` are fine. I don't know what `scriereFaraEnterInput` or `scriere` do but maybe start there.

Comment: @nullforce I'm typing "masculin", but it gives me "alegere invalida" (invalid choice). Howeevr, when i type " masculin" (" " + " masculin"), it gives me the correct choice.

Comment: @JohnWu scriereFaraInputEnter makes the text flow completely by itself on the same line, while scriere needs input and starts a new line. I don't think there would be any problem there, but i could be wrong

Comment: I think it may be the `Console.ReadKey()` in your `scriere()` function. If you could put a `Console.WriteLine(raspuns);` after the `raspuns=Console.ReadLine();` statement and provide the non-space prefixed input, what is output? I'm expecting that is "asculin" because the `m` gets read into `ReadKey`.

Comment: @nullforce, yeah, that's exactly what's happening! it writes "asculin" because it takes the "m" into Console.ReadKey.

Comment: Please use PascalCase when naming methods in C#, not camelCase